# Delivering image from S3 to React client via Context API and Express server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, amazon-s3

I'm trying to download a photo from an AWS S3 bucket via an express server to serve to a react app but I'm not having much luck. Here are my (unsuccessful) attempts so far.

The Workflow is as follows:

- Client requests photo after retrieving key from database via Context API
- Request sent to express server route (important so as to hide the true location from the client)
- Express server route requests blob file from AWS S3 bucket
- Express server parses image to base64 and serves to client
- Client updates state with new image

**React Client**

```
const [profilePic, setProfilePic] = useState('');
useEffect(() => {
            await actions.getMediaSource(tempPhoto.key)
                .then(resp => {
                    console.log('server resp: ', resp.data.data.newTest) // returns ����\u0000�\u0000\b\u0006\
                    const url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                    const blobUrl = url.createObjectURL(resp.data.data.newTest);
                    console.log("blob ", blobUrl);
                    setProfilePic({ ...profilePic, image : resp.data.data.newTest });
                })
                .catch(err => errors.push(err));
}
```

**Context API** - just axios wrapped into its own library

```
    getMediaContents = async ( key ) => {
        return await this.API.call(`http://localhost:5000/${MEDIA}/mediaitem/${key}`, "GET", null, true, this.state.accessToken, null);
    }
```

**Express server route**

```
router.get("/mediaitem/:key", async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        const { key } = req.params;
        // Attempt 1 was to try with s3.getObject(downloadParams).createReadStream();
        const readStream = getFileStream(key);
        readStream.pipe(res);

        // Attempt 2 - attempt to convert response to base 64 encoding
        var data = await getFileStream(key);
        var test = data.Body.toString("utf-8");

        var container = '';
        if ( data.Body ) {
            container = data.Body.toString("utf-8");
        } else {
            container = undefined;
        }

        var buffer = (new Buffer.from(container));
        var test = buffer.toString("base64");
        require('fs').writeFileSync('../uploads', test); // it never wrote to this directory
        console.log('conversion: ', test); // prints:  77+977+977+977+9AO+/vQAIBgYH - this doesn't look like base64 to me. 
        delete buffer;
        res.status(201).json({ newTest: test });
        
    } catch (err){
        next(ApiError.internal(`Unexpected error > mediaData/:id GET -> Error: ${err.message}`));
        return;
    }
});
```

**AWS S3 Library** - I made my own library for using the s3 bucket as I'll need to use more functionality later.

```
const getFileStream = async (fileKey) => {
    const downloadParams = {
        Key: fileKey,
        Bucket: bucketName
    }
    
    // This was attempt 1's return without async in the parameter
    return s3.getObject(downloadParams).createReadStream();

    // Attempt 2's intention was just to wait for the promise to be fulfilled. 
    return await s3.getObject(downloadParams).promise();
}

exports.getFileStream = getFileStream;
```

If you've gotten this far you may have realised that I've tried a couple of things from different sources and documentation but I'm not getting any further. I would really appreciate some pointers and advice on what I'm doing wrong and what I could improve on.

If any further information is needed then just let me know.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it be useful for you, that's how i get image from S3, and process image on server

Create temporary directory

```
     createTmpDir(): Promise<string> {
            return mkdtemp(path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'tmp-'));
        }
```

Gets the file

```
 readStream(path: string) {
        return this.s3
            .getObject({
                Bucket: this.awsConfig.bucketName,
                Key: path,
            })
            .createReadStream();
    }
```

How i process file

```
async MainMethod(fileName){
        const dir = await this.createTmpDir();
     const serverPath = path.join(
            dir,
            fileName
        );
     await pipeline(
                this.readStream(attachent.key),
                fs.createWriteStream(serverPath + '.jpg')
            );
   



    const createFile= await sharp(serverPath + '.jpg')
                .jpeg()
                .resize({
                    width: 640,
                    fit: sharp.fit.inside,
                })
                .toFile(serverPath + '.jpeg');
    
            const imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync(serverPath + '.jpeg');
    
//my manipulations


            fs.rmSync(dir, { recursive: true, force: true }); //delete temporary folder



}
```

Comment: Hi Ncado, thanks for taking the time to share your solution. Much appreciated.  If I understandstand correctly, you create a temp folder, put the file there, then delete it once it's finished loading. Is there a reason you didn't use readstreams to pipe the data from s3 via the express server to your client? I'm trying to understand the pros and cons.

Comment: @spoons , yes, you understood everything correctly